# Jquery Smooth Scrolling jumps instead of scrolling - How do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to add "Smooth Scrolling" through Jquery to my HTML Site.

It just jumps instead of a smooth scroll effect.

I tried many differnt Jquery codes but none worked with the jumping problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function scrollToSection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $section = $($(this).attr('href')); 
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $section.offset().top
    }, 100);
  }
  $('[data-scroll]').on('click', scrollToSection);
}(jQuery));
```

My HTML Code :

Anchors (Nav)

```
<div class="inner">
    <a data-scroll href="#1" class="subNavBtn">ABOUT</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#2" class="subNavBtn">TERMINE</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#3" class="subNavBtn">RECORDINGS</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#4" class="subNavBtn">FOTOS</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#5" class="subNavBtn">VIDEOS</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#6" class="subNavBtn">CONTACT</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#7" class="subNavBtn">FREUNDE</a>
</div>
```

A Section i want to scroll to :

```
<section id="1">
    <div class="div abouthead">
            <div class="inner">
                <!--
                <h1>Ich bin <b>Heinz Lichius</b><br>Jazz Musiker, Platzhalterwort, Performer, Künstler</h1>
            -->
            <section>
<p>
 Heinz begann als Kind mit dem Schlagzeugspielen. Inspiriert durch seinen Vater nahm Jazz eine prägende Rolle ein, nicht nur stilistisch sondern konzeptionell. Nach einer klassisch geprägten Ausbildung und diversen Jazzworkshops studierte er an der Musikhochschule in Hamburg, wo er seit 1990 lebt.
            </p><p>
Verschiedene Projekte führten ihn um den Globus, so spielte er mit den Bigbands des NDR, des HR, Metropol Orchestra und Roger Cicero, dem Jonas Schoes Quartett mit Buggy Braune und Pepe Berns, Schumannize, Solea, Jon Hammond, Jürgen Attig, Lutz Büchner, Lorenz Bösche, Stephan Abel, Jo Gallardo´s Latino Blue, Nils Gessinger, Ulita Knaus, Peter Weniger, Paul O`Brien, Ulla Meinecke, Orange Blue,...
 </p><p>
Heinz unterrichtet an der Hochschule für Musik, Theater und Medien Hannover, der Hochschule für Musik und Theater Hamburg sowie der Hamburg School of Music.
</p>
            </section>

        </div>
    </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: use `3000` or `4000` interval in your animation so it look like scrolling

Comment: @NishargShah already tried - does not work !

Comment: give me your code so, i will try

Comment: @NishargShah https://jsfiddle.net/f4ed7vjw/

Comment: it looks fine, where is the problem ?

Comment: @NishargShah it works in the jsfiddle but somehow it doesnt work when i open the file in any browser

Comment: so i cant do anything, thanks!!

Comment: @NishargShah any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: you can check your code by compare it, first check your library called or not

Comment: Works optimal at 750.